# Can we apply to GridSearchCV to Logistic regression .?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, supervised-learning, gridsearchcv

When I apply GridSearchCV to my model Logistic Regression, it's continuously throwing below error.
I understand that it's trying to convert string to float. But that's was my data. So how can I convert my x value to float? Can any please hep me with this issue. Thank you.

```
Error: could not convert string to float: 'great im readi go home'
```

Sample data

**Airline_sentiment     text**

```
0     said <br/>
1     plu youv ad commerci experi tacki <br/>
2     didnt today must mean need take anoth trip<br/>

penalty = ['l1', 'l2']<br/>
C = np.logspace(0, 4, 10)<br/>
hyperparameters = dict(C=C, penalty=penalty)<br/>
gs = **GridSearchCV**(lr,hyperparameters,cv=5)<br/>
```

Comment: Yes you can apply it, refer the docs please.; ML models can only take in "number or numeral representations" of the same, they generally don't take raw strings as such directly, so go for a tf-idf+log reg baseline!

Comment: Do you mean, instead of a string of do I need to apply tfidf x matrix value .?

Comment: Yep, I would recommend checking out scikit learn examples first.. They are very well written with reusable code blocks to get you started. Your error code is very clear imho

Comment: Okay..Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the first thing you should do is to convert your data to a numeric type.

Maybe this starter tutorial can help you 
https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-natural-language-processing-nlp-323cc007df3d

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: then upvote please :)